# Which elementary calculation makes correct the equation? $-\log|\sqrt{1+x^2}-x|=\log|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x|$

Tags: calculus

> Which elementary calculation corrects the equation?
> $$-\log|\sqrt{1+x^2}-x|=\log|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x|$$

I find alternative forms with the following rule:
$$ \log_{\alpha} \frac{1}{a} =  \log_{\alpha} a^{-1} =  -\log_{\alpha} a$$

but I always have a "$-$" sign that I can't manage to simplify

(assuming that log is the natural logarithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to multiply and divide by the conjugate expression.

\begin{align*}
\log|\sqrt{1+x^2} + x|= & \log \left(\dfrac{\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\right|\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\right|}{\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\right|}\right) = \log \dfrac{1}{\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\right|}\\
 = & -\log\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\right|
\end{align*}

The calculations hold as long as $\sqrt{1+x^2}+x \ne 0 $ and $\sqrt{1+x^2} - x \ne 0$. You can check that these expression are never zero and the relation in valid for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thanks a lot, I appreciated ; )

Answer (score 1):

Now look that $\log|\sqrt{1+x^2}-x| + \log|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x| = \log(|\sqrt{1+x^2}-x||\sqrt{1+x^2}+x|) = \log(1)=0$. I think this is enough to show your equation. As inside log, you are using mod function so it is defined correctly, and $\sqrt{1+x^2}-x$ and $\sqrt{1+x^2}+x$ are non zero for all values of $\mathbb{R}$.